# Determining UpperCase and LowerCase comparing to code block

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, conditional-operator

I was experimenting with adding short-hand to the document object based on the camel case naming convention. For instance the following code will append `document` with `qS` that is short-hand for `querySelector` and `aEL` which is short-hand for `addEventListener`

```
let b, d, e; 
for(let k in(d=document)) d[k[0]+k.split("").filter(_=>_<{}).join("")] = d[k];

e=_=>d.qS(_);
b=_=>d.aEL.bind(_);
```

I'm declaring `d` as `document` and then iterating through each of its keys, determining the camel case letters (`k[0]` is the first letter which is lowercase and then I filter the key to find any uppercase letters), and then apply the first lowercase letter and any uppercase letters as a new method on `document` that references the original method - ergo `document.querySelector` becomes `d.qS`

At some point I learned the trick of comparing a character to braces to determine its case. a.e.

```
"c"<{}; //false
"C"<{}; //true

"E"<{}; //true
"e"<{}; //false
```

The issue is that I don't understand how this works, though it seems to work perfectly all the time. I'm not exactly sure what a code block is evaluated to as a comparative and it's difficult to Google, and even after sifting through codegolf and SO I haven't found an answer. I'm hoping someone could explain this?

NOTE: I realize code explanations are frowned upon but I did check the meta to determine if this was valid https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188079/where-to-ask-for-code-explanation

Comment: If you check alert({}) then it will show [object Object]. Here your comparison will take place as string comparison. So Uppercase A-Z have ASCII value from 65-90. “[“ have ASCII value as 91 and Lowercase a-z have ASCII value from 97-122. So as per ASCII values for Uppercase letters your code returns true and for lowercase letters false.

Comment: @KaranPatel - thats great explanation, I think you should write it as answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check alert({}) then it will show [object Object]. Here your comparison will take place as string comparison. So Uppercase A-Z have ASCII value from 65-90. “[“ have ASCII value as 91 and Lowercase a-z have ASCII value from 97-122. So as per ASCII values for Uppercase letters your code returns true and for lowercase letters false.

Comment: Oh, duh! haha. I was definitely overthinking it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: In JavaScript, it's the UTF-16 code unit values that matter. ASCII is not known to JavaScript.

Comment: @TomBlodget does that change the validity of the answer?

Comment: @zfrisch The answer would be valid if restated almost identically. But understanding would be based on familiarity with JavaScript and UFT-16.

Comment: @TomBlodget Thanks for the information. It's really helpful. I've checked for UTF-16 character set and it has same sequence for ASCII. So, even though javascript uses UTF-16 it will work the same.